# Unable to navigate Google Map to location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using Google Maps in iOS. I have added map in subview. But **animateToLocation** method doesn't work although it works fine if I assign mapView to whole view with

`self.view = mapView_`

```
[mapView_ animateToLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.868, 151.208)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by change outlet type GMSMapView and setting camera in viewDidLoad method.

in .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86  longitude:131.20   zoom:6];
self.mapView.camera = camera;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:131.20
                                                             zoom:6];

    self.map1.camera = camera;
```